# how to increase value of input type text after submitting data values into database

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

If I click on submit button then kot value will be increased by 1...initially it will be 0, and after submitting data into databaseit the page will be redirected to that page only.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="kot_no">KOT No</label>

      <input type="text" id="kot_no" name="kotno" value="" class="option">

      <label for="table_no">Table No</label>
      <input type="text" id="table_no" name="tableno" class="option" placeholder="0">
      <br>
      <br>

      <label for="Menu">Enter Menu Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter menu name" name="menuname">
      <br>
      <br>

      <label for="quantity">Enter Quantity</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Quantity" name="quantity" style="margin-left: 25px">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 124px" class="button">
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should provide your code too to assist us.

Comment: You can make use of session , cookies or on isset of your submit  you can get the value from DB and increment it and display in your textbox

Comment: what you have done sofar?